# Error during deploying a library to CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods

I've created my first pod, both `spec & lib` validations passed. 
So I pushed the spec to the Specs repository:

```
pod trunk push SlidingTabBar.podspec
```

But after validation I got this error:

```
[!] An internal server error occurred. 
Please check for any known status issues at https://twitter.com/CocoaPods and try again later.
```

If I try it again I'll get this error:

```
[!] Unable to accept duplicate entry for: SlidingTabBar (0.1.0)
```

What can I do to fix this?